# How to input a SQL query as a SQL column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My current SQL Server query looks like this:

```
select distinct a.xref, b.account, a.mark.price
from xxx."xxx" a, yyy."yyy" b
where a.cobdate = '20240226'
  and b.cobdate = '20240226'
  and a.xref = b.xref
  and b.account in ('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz')
```

I want to make it such that the hardcoded cobdates '20240226' are taken from something like: `MAX(a.cobdate)` and `MAX(b.cobdate)`.

`cobdate` is a column in both tables a and b.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Comma-delimited table join syntax was deprecated over thirty years ago

Comment: It's *2024*, it's *long past* time you adopted the ANSI-92 JOIN syntax, it did come out **32 years ago**. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 1):

don't use [deprecated syntax of join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/118796/sr0010-avoid-using-deprecated-syntax-when-you-join)

```
  select distinct  a.xref, b.account, a.mark_price
  from xxx."xxx" a
  join yyy."yyy" b
  on  a.xref = b.xref
  where   a.cobdate = (SELECT MAX(a.cobdate) FROM xxx."xxx" AS a)
     and  b.cobdate = (SELECT MAX(b.cobdate) FROM yy."yyy"  AS b)
     and  b.account in ('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz')
```

Answer (score -2):

there are many ways to structure your SQL -
one is just to swap out the literals with a select statement

```
select distinct a.xref, b.account, a.mark.price
from xxx."xxx" a, yyy."yyy" b
where a.cobdate = (select max(dt) from somewhere)
and b.cobdate = '20240226'
and a.xref = b.xref
and b.account in ('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz')
```